# compile boost under linux without being root

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, boost

how i can compile boost under linux without write in system folders.
I need to get headers files and shared libraries of boost in one my specific folder.

Comment: Did you read the [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to be root to compile Boost on Linux. Moreover, many Boost libraries are header only so no compilation is needed. see also [Building and Installing the Library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/install.html) and [Easy Build and Install](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html#easy-build-and-install) for more details.